# cakephp ldap login with idbroker plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, ldap

I am blocked with a strange problem. I have added a connection with auth to my application. This is a ldap connection, to do this is use the idbroker plugin from analogrithems. It works well in the developpement mode (Configure::write('debug', 2); in core.php), but when I put it to 0 the plugin is not able make request to the ldap. I have some error.
The error in the log is

2014-07-11 08:37:28 Ldap.error: Query Params Failed:Array
(
    [conditions] => (&(objectclass=group) member=CN=toto,OU=Users,OU=Paris,OU=France,DC=world,DC=local))

[fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
            [1] => 
            [2] => +
            [3] => 
        )

```
[joins] => Array
    (
    )

[limit] => 
[offset] => 
[order] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[page] => 1
[group] => 
[callbacks] => 1
[scope] => sub
[type] => search
[targetDn] => DC=world,DC=local
```

)
 Error: Operations error

I try to debug it by myself, but I can't.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  If not, is it on the same server that dev mode works, but live does not?

Comment: I haven't find any solution for this. The server is the same. I had changed the value of debug mode. In order to do this in my application, I have rewrite my own function to login thru a ldap